# C++ 11: smart pointer and input parameters - reference or pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11

i'm using the new smart-pointer from C++ 11. I'm now confused what's the best way to pass and input value to an function.

The standard rule for method/function signatures is

> inputs: prefer const reference and pointer where you must (f.e. nullptr is a legal input)
>
> outputs:  should b e pointers.

But with smart-pointer things are more "complicated".

I understand that you should not pass the input as ...

- **unique_ptr** where the ownership is not transfered
- **shared_ptr** where the object should not be share the ownership.

... and use referece or pointer instead.

For me the problem with the standard rule is that the developer who is using the function must dereference the pointer from the smart-pointer and he should always check if the result is not nullptr, so there is an "always" manual checking code.

```
void foo(const MyClass& obj)
{
    ...
}

void main()
{
    auto a = make_unique<MyClass>();
    if(*a) // always check dereference
    {
        foo(*a);
    }
}
```

Instead, passing the input as const pointer, the usability is easier, but nullptr would be an "legal" value.

```
void foo(const MyClass* obj)
{
    ...
}

void main()
{
    auto a = make_unique<MyClass>();
    foo(a.get()); //easier to use, but nullptr is a "legal" value
}
```

Can anybody share his opinion when you use pointer, when references and how do you deal with deref's in that case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is "Don't let your unique pointer become null" a reasonable answer for you?

Comment: Why are you using smart pointers when you don't really use them? And I also recommend you look at the smart pointers from a resource ownership perspective instead of as simply auto-deleting pointers: Can a resource have multiple simultaneous owners (`std::shared_ptr`) or only a single owner at a time (`std::unique_ptr`).

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg ups: typo. Edit the post. thx

Comment: *"the standard rule for method/function signatures"* - is that your own rule-of-thumb, or taken from somewhere...?

Comment: if(*a) if still wrong, just write if(a). I suggest you take another look an the smart pointer API

Comment: Oh and by the way, you don't have to use dereference in the `if` condition, the smart pointers have operators so they can be used as normal pointers (e.g. `if (a)` is enough). See e.g [`std::unique_ptr::operator bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_bool).

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg i'm using smart pointers, but when a function does not  take ownership of the given object, a pointer or reference is always better because you didn't know which smart-pointer the dev is using or he didn't use smart pointer at all. That's why C++ 11 introduce observer_ptr.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg if(a), good hint. Thx

Comment: @TonyD That's what all mature C++ guidelines have => so no, that not my rule

Comment: @tonka, I didn't see any guideline that says "outputs: should b e pointers." Actually I would usually say that returning a raw pointer by value from a function, if it is an owning pointer, is a code smell. If for instance the function produced a new object on the heap, it is in most cases better to return unique_ptr or shared_ptr to it, imo.

Comment: @TartanLlama "Don't let your unique pointer become null" answer my question. thx

Comment: @ChrisBeck I mean output (optional) in the signature! If the object creates a new object (f.e. factory) i always pass it back a unique_ptr.
https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Reference_Arguments

Comment: @tonka: I see. Yeah that is a standard idiom inherited from C, using a "maybe null" pointer passed as argument. An alternative you could consider is to pass a `std::optional<T&>` instead of a `T*` -- I don't actually do this right now, but I do consider it somewhat "self-documenting" which I like, even if it is more complicated. Especially when it can actually be `std::optional<T>`, e.g. `std::optional<double>` or something, I tend to think that is better, as being somewhat "self-documenting" what your intent is, and you are taking yourself further away from potential undefined behavior

Comment: @ChrisBeck nice. Thanks for that hint.

Comment: `make_unique<T>()` doesn't return `nullptr` but throws in case of failure, so no "if" check required.

Comment: @Jarod42 that's only a super simple demo, i don't wanna a complex code in stackoverflow ;-) . In my example you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to check if the pointer points to an allocated object or if it is instead null, use `std::unique_ptr::operator bool` which will return true if the pointer is valid and false if there is no object created yet:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_bool

This is better, and simpler, than using `get()` for this purpose.

Generally, with `unique_ptr` you do not pass the smart pointer itself to any functions, but when you want to pass a true pointer, you pass the return of `get()`, which is a non-owning normal pointer that the non-owning function can use. The pointer is still managed by the owning smart pointer. Common C++ guidelines encourage use of a normal pointer only for non-owning functions or classes that receive this pointer from a smart pointer elsewhere.